# ¿Debo usar la 'a personal' con un personaje antropomorfo?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, persona-gramatical, a-personal

Se usa la *a personal* cuando el objeto es una persona.

E.g.: Veo *a* mi hermana. (No se dice "Veo mi hermana.")

¿Se usa la *a personal* con personajes antropomorfos que *no son humanos*?

E.g.: ¿Cuáles están bien de las siguientes oraciones?

- Los rebeldes reparan *a* R2-D2. (o: "Los rebeldes reparan R2-D2".)
- Mi hermana besó *a* un vampiro. (o: "Mi hermana besó un vampiro.")
- ¿Conoce Ud. *a* SpongeBob SquarePants? (o: "¿Conoce Ud. SpongeBob SquarePants?")
- El Capitán Kirk va a atacar *a* dos Klingons. (o: "Capitán Kirk va a atacar dos klingons.")
- Pinkie Pie abraza *a* Rainbow Dash. (o: "Pinkie Pie abraza Rainbow Dash.")

¿Hay reglas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aunque se la llama habitualmente *a personal*, esta preposición se usa no sólo cuando el objeto directo es una persona, sino en la mayoría de los casos en que se trata de un ser animado, sea real o imaginario, o a un objeto que está siendo personificado o tratado como un ente animado.

Todos los ejemplos que das son de seres animados ficticios o imaginarios (un vampiro es imaginario y aunque no está vivo, es animado, porque se mueve, actúa, habla, se alimenta, etc., como una persona o un animal; R2D2 es una máquina, pero es animado porque se lo muestra en la ficción como un ser con inteligencia, que habla y se mueve con intención; y así con los demás). Por lo tanto, en todos es correcto usar la *a personal*.

Sería también correcto usar *a personal* con los siguientes:

- la momia de Imhotep en *[The Mummy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120616/)*,
- el alienígena de *[E.T.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083866/)*,
- el organismo de *[The Blob](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051418/)*,
- el organismo de *[The Thing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/)*...

... incluso aunque estos dos últimos no sean en absoluto antropomorfos.

Las plantas no se consideran normalmente seres animados, pero algunas personas pueden decir *abrazar **a** un árbol* si quieren enfatizar que el árbol es una criatura viva semejante a nosotros.

Tampoco diríamos que *el mundo* es un ser animado, pero la expresión *abrazar al mundo* existe, por ejemplo, en [un poema de A. Pizarnik](http://www.los-poetas.com/e/pizarnik1.htm).

Comment: Imagino que en la expresión «abrazar al mundo», el mundo es equivalente de «las personas del mundo», pero bueno, tampoco haría falta que lo interpretásemos así para justificar el uso.  Yo suelo decir a los alumnos que si a la cosa la tratamos con el cariño que corresponde al de una persona, queda justificado (así diferenciamos mascotas de ganado, androides de máquinas cotidianas, a la vez que permitimos que dos personas traten la misma cosa de formas distintas — las vacas por ejemplo para los del campo y los de la ciudad)

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar algo breve acerca de los animales?  ¿Cuáles usan la *a personal* y cuáles no?  Esta Q-A lo estoy considerando para proponer como canónico (quizás agregando una versión corta en inglés).

Answer (score 7):

Sí. En todos tus ejemplos hay que incluir la "a". Se aplica a cualquier ser/personaje animado.

Apéndice: primer resultado en Google:
http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Complemento%20directo%20preposicional.htm

> «Aunque existen excepciones, lo habitual es que el CD lleve la preposición a cuando su referente es específico y animado
>
> *No encuentro mi libro*;
>
> *No encuentro a mi gato*.
>
> Si el referente es animado, pero no identificable, aparece generalmente sin preposición. Contrastan así
>
> *Busca (una) traductora* (‘alguna, la que sea’) y
>
> *Busca a una traductora* (‘una en particular’).
>
> Tiende a suspenderse esta regla cuando es necesario evitar posible ambigüedades:
>
> Casos en los que el sujeto y el CD con referentes inanimados son permutables: *La virtud vence al vicio*.
>
> Circunstancias en las que el CD con referente animado coincide con otro complemento que se construye con a (*Entregaron al culpable / Entregaron el culpable a la policía*.
>
> La presencia y la ausencia de la preposición depente también de la naturaleza semántica del verbo. Así, hay verbos, como ayudar o servir, que exigen siempre la preposición (*Ayuda a los enfermos*), mientras que otros, como los existenciales haber o tener, no la llevan nunca (*Hay muchas personas; Isabel tiene dos hijos*).
>
> Hay, incluso, verbos que cambian de significado en función de la presencia o ausencia de la preposición: *abandonar un pueblo* (‘irse de él’) ~ *abandonar a un pueblo* (‘no cuidarlo’).» [RAE: *Nueva gramática básica de la lengua española*. Madrid: Espasa, 2011, p. 197-198]

Answer (score 5):

Aunque ya tienes dos respuestas válidas, me voy a permitir citar el artículo del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas correspondiente a la [preposición "**a**"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=a#11), donde se listan los casos donde se *debe*, donde se *puede*, y donde *no* se debe usar antes del objeto/complemento directo.

Copio solamente los casos en que es obligatorio usarlo u omitirlo; los casos en que son válidas ambas opciones, así como los ejemplos (que he quitado para ahorrar espacio), los puedes consultar en el propio artículo:

> **1.1. Uso forzoso:**
>
> **a)** Ante nombres propios de persona o de animal.
>   **b)** Ante nombres colectivos de persona cuyo referente es determinado o consabido.
>   **c)** Ante nombres comunes de persona cuyo referente es un individuo concreto, y no uno cualquiera entre varios posibles.
>   **d)** Ante nombres comunes de persona que, aun siendo inespecíficos o no consabidos, son complemento directo de verbos que suponen afectación física o psíquica (*acompañar, admirar, afectar, alabar, amar, empujar, engañar, golpear, maltratar, matar, odiar, perjudicar, saludar*, etc.).
>   **e)** Ante nombres comunes de persona precedidos de un indefinido, cuando son complemento directo de verbos de percepción como *mirar, observar* y *oír*. (Con otros verbos de percepción como *ver* y *conocer*, puede aparecer o no la preposición; → 1.2b).
>   **f)** Ante las formas tónicas de los pronombres personales *mí, ti, sí, él, ella, usted, nosotros/as, vosotros/as, ustedes, ellos/as*.
>   **g)** Ante pronombres demostrativos o posesivos cuyo referente es una persona.
>   **h)** Ante los pronombres indefinidos cuyo referente es una persona (*alguien, alguno, nadie, ninguno, todos, uno*, etc.), salvo cuando funcionan como complemento directo del verbo *haber* (→ 1.3e).
>   **i)** Ante los relativos de persona *quien*, *el que*, *la que* y sus plurales, cuando ejercen la función de complemento directo del verbo subordinado. A diferencia de *quien*, el relativo *que*, cuando tiene antecedente de persona y se usa sin artículo, nunca lleva preposición en función de complemento directo.
>   **j)** Ante el pronombre interrogativo de persona *quién*, y ante el pronombre interrogativo *cuál* referido a persona.
>   **k)** Ante nombres de cosa, para evitar ambigüedades, cuando el sujeto y el complemento van pospuestos al verbo.
>   **l)** Ante nombres de cosa, cuando son complemento directo de verbos que significan orden lineal o jerárquico, como *preceder* o *seguir*, y otros como *acompañar, complementar, modificar* (en el sentido gramatical de ‘servir de adjunto o complemento’) o *sustituir* (en el sentido de ‘ocupar el puesto [de otra cosa]’).
>   **m)** Ante nombres de cosa que designan colectivos formados por personas, del tipo *colegio, empresa, comité, consejo, institución, comunidad*, etc., cuando el verbo denota una acción que solo puede ejercerse sobre personas, y no sobre cosas.
>
> **1.3. No se usa**:
>
> **a)** Ante nombres comunes que designan objetos inanimados.
>   **b)** Ante nombres comunes de persona en plural que carecen de determinante.
>   **c)** Ante nombres propios de países o ciudades. Pero si estos nombres denotan no una realidad meramente geográfica, sino el conjunto de sus ciudadanos, se admite la preposición.
>   **d)** Ante nombres propios usados como comunes.
>   **e)** Con el verbo impersonal *haber*, el complemento directo, aun denotando persona, se construye sin preposición.
>   **f)** Con el verbo *tener*, el complemento directo de persona, si es indeterminado, se construye sin preposición; pero si va acompañado de un adjetivo en función de complemento predicativo que denota estados transitorios, se construye con preposición.