# ¿Por qué se dice "necesito un médico" pero "necesito a un doctor"? ¿Cual es la razón gramatical para esto?

Tags: gramática

Por un lado decimos  "*Necesito **a una persona*** para que me ayude"

Pero por otro decimos "*Necesito* ***un médico*** para que me ayude"

Otros ejemplos:

*Necesito un bolígrafo, necesito a un ayudante*

¿Existe alguna  razón gramatical concreta para  esto?

Comment: Este texto de la NGLE que voy a transcribir ya fue citado (y tu pregunta fue indirectamente respondida) aquí: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22713/debo-usar-la-a-personal-con-un-personaje-antropomorfo. Dice: "Si el referente es animado, pero no identificable, aparece generalmente sin preposición. Contrastan así

*Busca (una) traductora* (‘alguna, la que sea’) y

*Busca a una traductora* (‘una en particular’)"

Comment: @Gustavson Yo diría *necesito una persona* (sin *a*) pero sospecho que en eso hay bastante amplitud.

Comment: @pablodf76 Creo que también en ese caso aplica la definición que da la gramática: Necesito una persona cualquiera vs. Necesito a una persona en particular.

Comment: @Gustavson : Muchas gracias! No tenía ni idea de cómo formular la pregunta, de ahí el duplicado (la he marcado yo mismo).