# What is the meaning of 'Tráete el carro'? Why is 'tráete' used instead of 'tráeme'?

Tags: pronombres

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Tráete el carro.

Context: A drug dealer orders her security chief to bring her a car so she can go somewhere.

Why does she say "tráete" instead of "tráeme" (dative of interest which indicates that the action benefits her) ?

Comment: is Tráete or Traete? (the first is *tú, tráete el carro*, the second *vos, traete el carro*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both words are imperative, an order.
Both make reference to bringing the car.
The difference is for whom is the car. "Tráeme" means that the car is for the person who is giving the order. "Tráete" does not has that meaning, the car might be for anyone.

If I receive the order "tráeme", I would bring the car and give the car keys to the drug dealer.
If I receive the order "tráete", I would bring the car and stay in the driver's seat.

Comment: This really hits the nail on the head.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any difference between "trae el carro" and "tráete el carro" ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista The difference between "trae" and "tráete" is the imperative of the second one. "Trae" sometimes might be a suggestion, "tráete" is closer to a command. I would never say "tráete" to my boss.

Answer (score 3):

The form "tráete" is more oriented to indicate a mandate or an order, it can be heard at different times, for example:

In a moment of urgency:
**"Traete el teléfono"** > 
*"Bring me the phone."*

That the person is angry
**"Traete rápido lo que olvidaste"** >
*"Bring back quickly what you forgot."*

In other cases it can also be applied between people who are close to each other -- it's an idiom in Latín América.

Whereas **"tráeme"** is a way that could be heard as less aggressive or imperative.

Comment: It works with other verbs, too: "Búscate un vaso de agua, hijito, que me muero de sed."

Comment: Yes, I would say: Go get the phone and Go get what you forgot. That is a colloquial match for the Spanish...

Answer (score 3):

**Traerse** means

*to bring [something/someone] with you [or whoever]*, or

*to bring [something/someone] along*.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/traerse):

> (uso enfático) to bring
>   me he traído la cámara *I’ve brought the camera ⧫ I’ve brought the camera with me*
>   no se trajo al novio *she didn’t bring her boyfriend*

[SpanishDict.com](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/traerse):

> 1b. to bring along
>   Tráete el perro cuando vamos al parque. *Bring the dog along when we go to the park.*
>   [Note: I think this would be better as "Tráete el perro cuando vayamos al parque."

So your sentence means

> Bring the car with you.

or

> Bring the car when you come.

Comment: Is "al" correct in "no se trajo al novio"? If so, what is the difference between that sentence and "no se trajo el novio" ?

Comment: You know, I wonder if here in this lowlife type of Mexican Spanish, they don't just mean: Bring the car around [like from the garage at a house to the front]. I don't think the Collins definition would apply here. Or: Go get the car.

Comment: @Lambie - maybe your idea aligns with the new answer from Santiago (which I think hits the nail on the head)?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - There are several Q-A pages about that.  I've been trying to get a tag set up for that topic.  Start with this one and see if it helps: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22713/9385

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks for the feedback. I know that "a" precedes people, but I got confused there. Never mind.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - Okay, good, glad you're clear.  What do you think, would the Q-A I linked to be a helpful canonical Q-A, in your opinion?

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, I agree it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

"Tráete" could be translated as "bring with you" the car.