# ¿Es correcto "eliminar a" o "eliminar" (sin a)?

Tags: gramática

Hasta donde tengo entendido, es cuestión de si el verbo es transitivo o intransitivo. "Eliminar" es transitivo, por lo que *a priori* me da la impresión que siempre es correcto decir, por ejemplo, "Eliminar un archivo". Sin embargo, he escuchado también "eliminar a [alguna persona]" principalmente en el sentido de una eliminación más completa y/o absoluta.

¿Es gramaticalmente incorrecto decir "eliminar a", o es simplemente una forma de dar un matiz más fuerte a la acción?

En una aplicación de software donde se pueden gestionar grupos de usuarios, el siguiente mensaje: "Este permiso le permite eliminar cualquier grupo" me causa la sensación de que debería decir "... eliminar a cualquier grupo", pero no estoy seguro de cómo justificaría ese cambio.

Comment: El [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=4&tipo2=0&iniItem=25&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=180620%5C016%5CC000O18062020161458048.1048.1044&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20eliminar%20a%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&marcas=0) recoge múltiples casos de **eliminar a**, y el [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll) aún más, por lo que no veo por qué no va a ser correcto o haya que justificarlo.

Comment: Esto parece un caso de [a personal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22713/24236). Los complementos directos que se refieren a una persona llevan "a", y los que se refieren a un objeto no llevan "a". Por ejemplo "Veo la casa" / "Veo a María".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay verbos que llevan o no "a" delante del complemento directo según el sentido del verbo.

> Hay, incluso, verbos que cambian de significado en función de la presencia o ausencia de la preposición: abandonar un pueblo (‘irse de él’) ~ abandonar a un pueblo (‘no cuidarlo’).» [RAE: Nueva gramática básica de la lengua española. Madrid: Espasa, 2011, p. 197-198] [Fuente](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Complemento%20directo%20preposicional.htm)

(En el primer caso, "pueblo" es concebido como un lugar --una cosa--, mientras que en el segundo se lo entiende como sus habitantes -- personas --.)

Si consideramos las distintas acepciones de "eliminar":

> 1. tr. Quitar o separar algo, prescindir de ello.
> 2. tr. Alejar o excluir a una o a muchas personas de una agrupación o de un asunto. U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. tr. En ciertas competiciones deportivas, vencer al rival, impidiéndole con ello seguir participando en la competición.
> 4. tr. Matar, asesinar.
> 5. tr. Dicho del organismo: Expeler una sustancia.
> 6. tr. Mat. En un sistema de ecuaciones con varias incógnitas, hacer desaparecer, por medio del cálculo, una de ellas.

claramente prescindimos de "a" cuando el objeto es inanimado (acepciones 1, 5 y 6) y la usamos cuando el objeto es animado (acepciones 2, 3 y 4).

El punto, me parece, es que un grupo de usuarios puede ser concebido como una entidad animada (un grupo de personas), en cuyo caso aplicaría la acepción 2, o como un grupo de elementos, en cuyo caso aplicaría la acepción 1. Según lo concibamos de un modo u otro, vacilaremos entre el uso y la omisión de la preposición.